# A continuous function $f$ verifies : $\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x).dx= +\infty$. $\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x).dx= -\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

In general,for a continuous function $f$ verifies : 
$\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x).dx= +\infty$.
$\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x).dx= -\infty$.
What can we say about $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x).dx$.
I took the example of $f(x)=2x$ it verifies the hypothesis,
and I've found that :
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} 2xdx$ doesn't exit !
I think there are examples where the integral may exist ! (like a finite number, or infinity).

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f$ exists if both $\int_{-\infty}^{0}f$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}f$ exists (and finite). But they are not finite in your case.

Comment: Yeah that's, the problems, there is some example where the integral in $\mathbb{R}$ equals $\infty$ ?

Comment: Integral itself doesn't exists, but see this [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), that makes sense of those kind of integrals.

Comment: there's a diffrence between equals $\infty$ and doesnt exist !

Comment: If the $\int_{-\infty}^0$ is $-\infty$, then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ cannot be $\infty$. It can be undefined, or $-\infty$, but not $\infty$.

Comment: if both $\int{0}{\infty}= \infty$ and  $\int{-\infty}{0}= -\infty$, is it always undefined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If principal values are good enough for you, you can say that for any integrable odd function $f$ the integral over $\mathbb{R}$ is 0. So, $$\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-a}^{a} f(x) dx=0.$$ Then of course you can generate a simple example where the PV is any number.

To get the PV to equal some $b\in \mathbb{R}$ you can take an odd function $f$ and manipulate it to a function $$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}\
h(x) \quad\text{for}\quad x\in [x_0,x_1],\\
f(x) \quad \text{else},
\end{cases}
$$
where $$\int_{x_0}^{x_1} h(x) dx=\int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(x) dx+b.$$ And if you want $g$ to be continious you must have $h(x_i)=f(x_i),i=0,1.$

Comment: Thank you, that really answer my question !